# Rsync command variable, bash script

Tags: bash, rsync

```
RSYNC="rsync -avzhe 'ssh -i /path/to/deploy_keys/id_rsa' --delete "

# Files
$RSYNC deploy@ip:/var/www/path1 /var/www/path1
$RSYNC deploy@ip:/var/www/path2 /var/www/path2
```

I'd like to introduce this RSYNC Variable to be more compact, but it throws an error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: deploy@ip:/var/www/path1
```

If i use only rsync inside the doublequotes, it works fine. For the sake of readability, i'd keep them separate command invocations.

Comment: Related question with a more descriptive title: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5730881/1328439

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that `eval` is dangerous. In addition to the array approach @Eugeniu Rosca suggested, you could also use a shell function:

```
my_rsync() {
    rsync -avzhe 'ssh -i /path/to/deploy_keys/id_rsa' --delete "$@"
}

my_rsync deploy@ip:/var/www/path1 /var/www/path1
my_rsync deploy@ip:/var/www/path2 /var/www/path2
```

BTW, you should read [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: IMHO this is the most beautiful in terms of invocation, so I rewrote the code to shell function style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the command string into a variable and evaluate it later, you can use `eval` or an alternative safer technique:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the command into an array
RSYNC=(rsync -avzhe 'ssh -i /path/to/deploy_keys/id_rsa' --delete)
# Run the command
"${RSYNC[@]}" deploy@ip:/var/www/path1 /var/www/path1
```

<sup>*[Why `eval` should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)*</sup>

Comment: I modified the script quickly, but it still throws the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @AronNovak add double quotes around `"${RSYNC[@]}"` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

After you assign a string to a variable and then submit it to shell again it is tokenized differently. Consider the following script

```
VAR="/bin/ls 'Test1 Test2'"
$VAR
```

It will throw two errors:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access 'Test1
/bin/ls: cannot access Test2'
```

You guessed it right, the apostrophes are no longer affecting tokenization. Instead they are treated as normal characters when the commandline arguments are fed to `/bin/ls`

While `eval` is rightly considered evil, it is by far the easiest way to get a script running. It stitches all the arguments into one line and applies the tokenizing procedure again.

```
RSYNC="rsync -avzhe 'ssh -i /path/to/deploy_keys/id_rsa' --delete "

# Files
eval $RSYNC deploy@ip:/var/www/path1 /var/www/path1
eval $RSYNC deploy@ip:/var/www/path2 /var/www/path2
```