# cmake doesn't correctly parse whitespace in command line parameter

Tags: bash, cmake, command-line-arguments, whitespace

When I call cmake like this, everything works:

`cmake -G'Android Gradle - Ninja' ..`

However, I'm setting up a bash script that lets me specify the target platform, changing the `-G` argument dynamically.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CMAKE_GENERATOR="Ninja"
if [[ $TARGET_PLATFORM == "android" ]] ; then
    CMAKE_GENERATOR="'Android Gradle - Ninja'"
fi

cmake -G$CMAKE_GENERATOR ..
```

This gives me the following error:

`CMake Error: Could not create named generator 'Android`

Apparently cmake splits the generator name at the whitespace and interprets it as multiple arguments. I've tried multiple combinations of escaping the single/double quotes as well as the whitespaces but can't get it to work. I'm not even sure if this is a cmake or bash issue. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a question I asked a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730881/invoking-a-command-line-with-spaces-from-a-variable-in-a-bash-script

Comment: And apologies if I broke any rule by referring to my own previous question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes are missing in following command:

```
cmake -G$CMAKE_GENERATOR ..
```

should be

```
cmake -G"$CMAKE_GENERATOR" ..
```

because word splitting occurs after parameter expansion [more information in bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: That did it. Thanks for also linking to an explanation!